# Why can't I load my G3DB model into my libgdx game?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have been trying to load a 3d model that I made into my LibGDX game.  I've followed many different tutorials, but I keep getting the same error: `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` Which seems to stem from the line `if(loading && assets.update())`

Here is my code:

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private PerspectiveCamera camera;
    private ModelBatch modelBatch;
    private Environment environment;
    private AssetManager assets;
    private boolean loading;
    private Array<ModelInstance> instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();

    @Override
    public void create () {

        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

        camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
        camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
        camera.near = 1f;
        camera.far = 300f;
        camera.update();


        assets = new AssetManager();
        assets.load("assets/obj/tablegame.g3db", Model.class);
        loading = true;

    }

    private void doneLoading(){
        Model table = assets.get("assets/obj/tablegame.g3db", Model.class);
        ModelInstance tableInst = new ModelInstance(table);
        instances.add(tableInst);
        loading = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void render () {
        if (loading && assets.update())
            doneLoading();

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(camera);
        modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        modelBatch.dispose();
        instances.clear();
        assets.dispose();;
    }
}
```

Here is the full error string:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:579)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:380)
    at csgo.casino.game.Game.render(Game.java:65)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU.get(DirectFloatBufferU.java:253)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.extendBoundingBox(Mesh.java:668)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.extendBoundingBox(Mesh.java:605)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.calculateBoundingBox(Mesh.java:587)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.model.MeshPart.update(MeshPart.java:124)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.convertMesh(Model.java:263)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.loadMeshes(Model.java:231)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.load(Model.java:106)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.<init>(Model.java:102)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadSync(ModelLoader.java:114)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadSync(ModelLoader.java:35)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:141)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:504)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:378)
    ... 3 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many indices does your model have? You have to make sure that none of the nodes in your model exceed the index limit of 65535.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm still new to modeling.  I made it in blender.  Have any idea how I can find that?

Comment: I assume you used [fbx-conv](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv)? With that you can export the model as a Json file. The command should be something like this: `fbx-conv -o G3DJ <blender-file> <output-file>.g3dj`.  In this Json all the nodes, materials, vertices are printed out. Also when using the converter normally, you can add the `-v` flag to print additional output to the console.

Comment: Ok, so I had been getting a message saying my file had too many indices, but I've modified it and when I re-exported it, I no longer get that message in the converter.  I am, however, still getting the same error in my game.